# Why do I get the errors ambiguous field or unknown column in field list?

Tags: mysql, sql

I created these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Game` (

 `GameName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `GameGenre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `GameDescription` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `GameMode` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`GameName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `GameScoreTotal` (

 `ScoreID` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `GameName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `OverallScoreTotal` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 `GraphicsTotal` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 `StoryTotal` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 `GameplayTotal` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 `TimeTotal` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ScoreID`),
  CONSTRAINT  FOREIGN KEY (`GameName`) REFERENCES `Game` (`GameName`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

My query needs to return all information from game table for the top ten games based on `GameScoreTotal.OverallScoreTotal`.

Queries I have tried:

```
SELECT GameName 
FROM Game 
FULL JOIN GameScoreTotal 
    ON Game.GameName=GameScoreTotal.GameName 
ORDER BY OverallScoreTotal DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10;

SELECT Game.GameName 
FROM Game 
FULL JOIN GameScoreTotal 
    ON Game.GameName=GameScoreTotal.GameName 
ORDER BY OverallScoreTotal DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Both tables have legitimate records within them.

Comment: So you have an `id` column for `GameScoreTotal`, but not `Game`?  While I relaize names are unique (mostly...), you'd probably be better advised to use an id there, too (and you can probably ditch `scoreId` and just use `gameId`, unless there are other requirements).  Consider labeling `TimeTotal` in the number of units it represents (minutes?) - and **don't** format it.  `OverallScoreTotal` is a derived value, and (usually) shouldn't be stored - it should be computed on the fly.  Consider creating a `Genre` table, and a `GameGenre` cross-table, allowing games to be part of multiple genres.

Comment: Also, why are you attempting to use an 'outer' join?  I would presume you would only care about the top ten games that both exist, and have a score.  As opposed to, well, games that may not exist, or may not have scores.

Comment: Well game names will be distinct in this project. Time total is in minutes but that will be said in the interface. Upon someone entering data in another table rating the values will be placed into OverallScoreTotal then divided by the number of individual ratings. For the purposes of this project I am only assigning one genre to eliminate complexity on that part. I just want to grab all the info form the game table but sort by the GameScoreTotal Overall ScoreTotal field, and only the higher ten numbers. Thanks for your help!!! But I don't think we solved it yet

Comment: Oh yea I am using a full join so that both tables must have the same GameName to produce a result.

Answer (score 1):

## Query 1

In your first query, the issue is that the field GameName exist in both the tables Game and GameScoreTotal. Hence the error `Column 'GameName' in field list is ambiguous`

## Query 2

MySQL doesn't have a *`FULL JOIN`*. [**Read here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) about MySQL JOIN Syntax.

Try the **`LEFT OUTER JOIN`** between *Game* and *GameScoreTotal* table, this join will fetch all records from Game table and all the matching records from *GameScoreTotal* table, if there are no matching records in *GameScoreTotal* table, NULL will be displayed.

You can also try **`INNER JOIN`**, which will fetch only the matching records between the two tables.

*Script*:

```
SELECT Game.GameName 
FROM Game 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GameScoreTotal 
    ON Game.GameName=GameScoreTotal.GameName 
ORDER BY OverallScoreTotal DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```